# Is there a low level alternative for bpy.ops.object.convert()?

Tags: python, mesh, meta-objects

I am using `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH', keep_original= False)` in a python function in blender to convert metaballs to a mesh. The script works fine when run from the text editor. However, the goal is to add the function to the render events via `bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append()` and `bpy.app.handlers.render_post.append()`

When the function using `bpy.ops.object.convert` is used in the handler, a polling error occurs. The typical recommendation is to either use overrides or low-level functions to eliminate the `polling/context` error. I would like to use low-level functions.

A code snippet in the `Blender 2.75a` low-level API for `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH', keep_original= False)`, where the selected object is a meatball, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [to_mesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=to_mesh#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) method

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

mball = bpy.data.objects.get("Mball")

if mball:
    me = mball.to_mesh(scene, False, 'PREVIEW')

    # add an object
    o = bpy.data.objects.new("MBallMesh", me)
    scene.objects.link(o)
    o.matrix_world = mball.matrix_world

    # not keep original
    scene.objects.unlink(mball)
```

Comment: Your `to_mesh(scene, False, 'PREVIEW')` will cause error in Blender 2.8

Comment: No kidding ? as it was answered in 2015.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar problem. And `to_mesh` did not help me, it still didn't work. I imported some curves and then tried to convert them to mesh and exception related to incorrect context occurred. After short investigation I discover that correct context for convert function means existence not-None `active_object` and not-None `selected_object` in `bpy.context`.
So the following code should work for conversion from/to mesh:

```
obj = D.objects[0] # the sample
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
obj.select = True
bpy.ops.object.convert.poll() # should return True now
```

Comment: sorry , your`bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
` will occur `bpy_prop_collection: attribute "active" not found` ,maybe it is the version issue

Comment: Yes it is a version issue. See date of answer. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126577/blender-2-8-api-python-set-active-object/126581#126581  `ob.select_set(True)` replaces `ob.select`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add that if you create the metaballs programmatically as in

```
metaball = bpy.data.metaballs.new('MetaBall')
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('MetaBallObject', metaball)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)

element = metaball.elements.new()
element.co = (0, 0, 0)
element.radius = 1.0
```

you need to add `bpy.context.scene.update()` after you created the metaballs. Then you can

```
mesh = obj.to_mesh(bpy.context.scene, False, 'PREVIEW')
new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('MetaBallMeshObject', mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(new_obj)
```

otherwise you won't have any geometry.

Comment: This creates an empty object. Do you know an updated version for 2.80 or 2.79b?