# Is there a low level alternative for bpy.ops.object.convert(target='CURVE')?

Tags: python, mesh, bezier-curves

(Note: Somebody asked [there](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39881/is-there-a-low-level-alternative-for-bpy-ops-object-convert) nearly the same question as me and got a very nice answer. However, this was to convert an object to a mesh. I have exactly the same context as this person but I want to convert a mesh to a curve and the answer does not adapt.
Hence I am copying the question's text below, adapting the appropriate parts.

I'm using `bpy.ops.object.convert(target='Curve')` in a Python function in Blender to convert the product of a `bisect(clear_inner, clear_outer)` to a curve, with the goal to bevel this curve later. The script works fine when run from the *Text Editor*. However, the goal is to add the function to the render events via `bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append()`.

When the function using `bpy.ops.object.convert` is used in the handler, a polling error occurs. The typical recommendation is to either use overrides or low-level functions to eliminate the polling/context error. I would like to use the low-level functions.

Comment: are you regenerating the 'Donor' Object also on each frame? (Donor = object that you perform bisection on.. )

Comment: @Zeffii: yes, I regenerate it at each frame.

Comment: @Zeffi, I just saw you removed you answer. What happened?

Comment: you described a narrow usecase for the _convert_ code, [my answer wouldn't be optimal](http://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/66476/3). If i can offer friendly advice it would be to modify your question to include the code you tried (i presume [something like this](https://gist.github.com/zeffii/165b33ba16c7f7790aa3ee8cac9bdd78) ) and ask if anyone knows how to achieve the `mesh->bisect->curve(->bevel)` while rendering frames.