# Blender 2.8 API, python, set active object

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I'm trying to amend an addon that I made for Blender 2.7X to work with Blender 2.80.
The problem is with

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = some_object
```

This is how I used to set an active object, the problem is, active property was removed in the new API!,reading other Q&As, I found 2 suggestions:

```
bpy.context.object
```

and

```
bpy.context.active_object
```

The problem is, both of these will return the already active object, but when I try to use them this way:

```
bpy.context.active_object = some_object
```

or

```
bpy.context.object = some_object
```

I'm getting an AttributeError: property is read-only!

I tried the documentation with no luck!

**EDIT:**

According to Blender 2.8 WIKI API changes:
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Dev:2.8/Source/LayersCollections/API-Changes

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active
```

changed into

```
bpy.context.render_layer.objects.active
```

This doesn't work, AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'render_layer'

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Use the view_layer**

Set [ViewLayer.active](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.LayerObjects.html#bpy.types.LayerObjects.active) to any object in view layer or `None`

```
context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
```

Note selecting has also changed from `ob.select = True` to

```
ob.select_set(True)
```

which together will emulate the general case  UI state of having the context object  both active and selected.

Comment: Great, many thanks @batFINGER, may I ask, how did you figure it out, even the wiki changes got it wrong!

Comment: Upgrading scripts. Read that wiki  a while back and remembered it was a `context.somelayer.objects.active` but not which one lol.   Pecking around in API in py console, looking for  active prop on some of new type  context layers objects collection, and on view_layer  bingo. Have a feeling it has been answered here before too.

Comment: Lol, I guess hacking skills are required to properly read the API

Comment: Wouldn't be able to do it without your help @batFINGER many thanks! https://github.com/sergeod9/Easy_Align_Addon/blob/master/Easy_Align_Addon_ver_1_0_3.py