# Select objects in scene by their object color

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I would like to select all the objects in the scene that have the same object color `Object.color` as the active object.

```
import bpy
active = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active
color=active.material_slots.data.color
for obj in bpy.data.objects.keys():
    colorSelect = obj.material_slots.data.color
    if colorSelect == color:
        #How do I select this object?
```

Comment: What exactly you'd like to do? Please provide a bit more context.

Comment: Given `obj is obj.material_slots.data` is the question: how to select all objects with same object color `obj.color`  as context object?

Comment: Yes - how to select all objects with same object color obj.color as context object?

Answer (score 2):

[Based on your comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161195/how-select-any-object-in-script#comment273135_161195), **I guess** you want to compare against the [viewport display color property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.color):

[image]

I think one easy way to compare color values is appending the components to a new list and compare the resulting lists using the `==` operator.

```
>>> [c for c in C.object.color]
>>> [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
>>>
>>> [c for c in C.object.color] == [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
>>> True
```

If you don't like lists for any reason, you can also convert the color to a tuple using the slice operator `[:]`, which is even shorter -> thanks to @batFINGER:

```
>>> C.object.color[:] == (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
True
```

Full script iterating through [Scene.objects](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.objects), comparing the color values (r,g,b,a) of each object against the values of [Context.object](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.object) and selecting the matches:

```
import bpy

ctx = bpy.context
obj = ctx.object

# Object color as list
obj_clr = [c for c in obj.color]

for o in ctx.scene.objects:
    if o != obj and o.type not in ('LIGHT', 'CAMERA', 'EMPTY'):
        # Compare both lists
        if [c for c in o.color] == obj_clr:
            o.select_set(True)

obj.select_set(False)
```

Be aware that there are might be issues with [floating point precision](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) when comparing the values. One way around that is using [`isclose(a, b, *, rel_tol=1e-09, abs_tol=0.0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) provided by the math module, which can be wrapped into a little helper function to test all 4 floats at once:

```
def compare_color(a, b, t=0.001):
    from math import isclose
    comp = {isclose(i, j, abs_tol=t) for i, j in zip(list(a),list(b))}
    return True if (len(comp) == 1 and next(iter(comp)) == True) else False
```

Another example comparing against [Material.diffuse_color](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html?highlight=diffuse_color#bpy.types.Material.diffuse_color) using the helper function:

```
import bpy

def compare_color(a, b, t=0.001):
    from math import isclose
    comp = {isclose(i, j, abs_tol=t) for i, j in zip(list(a),list(b))}
    return True if (len(comp) == 1 and next(iter(comp)) == True) else False

ctx = bpy.context
obj = ctx.object

# Object color as list
obj_clr = obj.active_material.diffuse_color

for o in ctx.scene.objects:
    if o != obj and o.type not in ('LIGHT', 'CAMERA', 'EMPTY'):
        # Compare both lists
        if compare_color(obj_clr, o.active_material.diffuse_color):
            o.select_set(True)
```

Further Reading: [Select an object by name in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132825/) and [Set active object in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/126577/)

Comment: or `C.object.color[:]`

Comment: Appreciated @batFINGER, but tbh I dont get why...?

Comment: IMO preferable to its equivalent  `[c for c in obj.color]` or similarly with  `bm.verts[:]`  etc

Answer (score 2):

**Similarly with `Vectors`**

@brockmann has absolutely nailed it.

*Here is another example using the length of `Vector` difference of the colors*

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
col = Vector(ob.color)

for o in context.scene.objects:
    o.select_set((Vector(o.color) - col).length < 1e-4)
```

To compare only the rgb and not a (alpha) parts, use one of

```
col = Vector(ob.color).to_3d()
col = Vector(ob.color).xyz
col = Vector(ob.color[3:])
```

to make the vector 3d `(r, g, b)`

To select only mesh objects with same rgb color as active

```
o.select_set(o.type == 'MESH' and (Vector(o.color).xyz - col.xyz).length < 1e-4)
```