# Python in Blender 2.8 - testing if two objects overlap in the XY Plane?

Tags: python

In Python is there a way to test if two objects overlap?

I am somewhat randomizing the location of two objects and I need to make sure that they do not overlap.

I have spent several hours (without success) trying to come up with my own algorithm, but I am now wondering if maybe I can use an existing function instead...

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: There are various ways of testing for intersection, some more complex than others. How precise do you need to be? Are the objects arbitrary polygonal meshes and you need exact intersection testing, or would just bounding box comparisons suffice? Are you randomizing the rotation and scale as well as location?

Comment: @acro cubes of uniform size, on the same plane on axis Z; some randomization of Y and X; rotated randomly somewhat on axis Z.

Comment: Consider: "python 2.8" is misleading -> Blender is using python 3.7 already

Comment: @acro, why this edit adding "in the XY plane"?

Comment: @lemon from vndep's add-on comment where he said the test for separation is for objects only varying in that plane. i'm not too experienced with the guidelines yet, thought it clarified the question?

Comment: @acro, yes, had not seen this comment.

Comment: @lemon was that ok as an edit, then? I did worry I was just being an overzealous noob with the new site features while making the 'python 2.8 / python in blender 2.8' change.

Comment: @acro, all is fine. With the constraints I've not seen your answer is the most accurate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a Python API to do that. [BVHTree.overlap](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.overlap)

It is nearly direct, we just need to convert objects vertices in world coordinates:

```
import bpy
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree

# Get the objects
obj1 = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
obj2 = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]

# Get their world matrix
mat1 = obj1.matrix_world
mat2 = obj2.matrix_world

# Get the geometry in world coordinates
vert1 = [mat1 @ v.co for v in obj1.data.vertices] 
poly1 = [p.vertices for p in obj1.data.polygons]

vert2 = [mat2 @ v.co for v in obj2.data.vertices] 
poly2 = [p.vertices for p in obj2.data.polygons]

# Create the BVH trees
bvh1 = BVHTree.FromPolygons( vert1, poly1 )
bvh2 = BVHTree.FromPolygons( vert2, poly2 )

# Test if overlap
if bvh1.overlap( bvh2 ):
    print( "Overlap" )
else:
    print( "No overlap" )
```

Comment: I am trying your script on two primitive flat planes which I have moved on the z axis so that they do not intersect each other but then translated them on the XY axes so that they overlap to some extend (from a top view perspective), however it fails to detect that the two objects are overlapping. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

With all the objects being same-sized cubes on the same Z, you only need to worry about XY.
Three possible levels to consider going about this, in increasing order of complexity:

1. Just rough it with circle separation. If you treat each object as if it were a circle, no Z-rotation will matter. A cube with half-width ('radius') 1 will fit inside a circle of radius sqrt(2) - with its corners touching that circle. In that case, the cheap and nasty quick way to detect all these sorts of overlaps is just using the distance formula between the object centers to see if that distance is less than two of these radii.
   Like...

   ```
   import bpy
   from math import sqrt

   def dist(a, b):
       dx = a.location[0] - b.location[0]
       dy = a.location[1] - b.location[1]
       return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

   minDist = 2 * circRadius

   cubes = [ob for ob in bpy.data.objects if ob.name.startswith("Cube")]

   for cube in cubes:
       for other in cubes:
           if other != cube:
               if dist(cube, other) < minDist:
                   print("%s and %s overlap." % (cube.name, other.name))
   ```

Note that this will report false positive overlaps on cubes that are closely aligned and close by each other, not touching, but still within the approximate circles.

2. If you want to get more 'proper' or accurate, that starts to get more into 'collision detection' topics. You may want to read up on how games check for overlaps, eg SAT (the separating axis theorem).
3. Blender definitely has utilities for doing this sort of thing internally. I don't know its internals well enough to know what's all in there, having not done this exact thing before, but it sounds like a common need. The boolean tool is bound to detect things exactly. Even just testing this basic stuff, I noticed in the Scripting workspace that there's internal modules like mathutils, mathutils.geometry, and that objects have functions such as closest_point_on_mesh, ray_cast, and so on.
   Familiarizing yourself with these and searching through/reading the API docs will pay dividends, if you need a more exact solution. For example, at a glance I also see spatial partitioning helpers such as mathutils.bvhtree, mathutils.kdtree, and others.

Comment: Assumes object origin is object center. Moving all verts any object  in edit mode demonstrates that the origin is arbitrary.  Perhaps calculate the COG instead. Also `dist = (a - b).xy.length`  With vectors there is almost never a need to code the Euclidean formula./

Answer (score 1):

This link helped me alot , but addinf depsgraph helped me after using modifiers

```
    depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
    
    
    #create bmesh objects
    bm1 = bmesh.new()
    bm2 = bmesh.new()
    
    #fill bmesh data from objects
    object_eval = obj1.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
    mesh_from_eval_obj1 = object_eval.to_mesh()
    bm1.from_mesh(mesh_from_eval_obj1)
    
    
    object_eval = obj2.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
    mesh_from_eval_obj2 = object_eval.to_mesh()
    bm2.from_mesh(mesh_from_eval_obj2)         

    #transform it here:
    bm1.transform(obj1.matrix_world)
    bm2.transform(obj2.matrix_world) 
    
    

    #make BVH tree from BMesh of objects
    obj_now_BVHtree = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm1)
    obj_next_BVHtree = BVHTree.FromBMesh(bm2)           

    #get intersecting pairs
    inter = obj_now_BVHtree.overlap(obj_next_BVHtree)

    print("i got this far 1")

    #if list is empty, no objects are touching
    if inter != []:
        print(obj1.name  + " and " +obj2.name + " are touching!")
    else:
        print(obj1.name + " and " + obj2.name + " NOT touching!")
    
    return 0
```

Comment: Consider using `bm.from_object` to get an evaluated bmesh. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146573/15543