# Check overlapping in pose position

Tags: python

I have the following code to check if two objects overlapping and it's works well, I don't understand how to check overlapping for objects in pose position

Source of this code: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150047/97742

```
import bpy
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree

# Get the objects
obj1 = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
obj2 = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]

# Get their world matrix
mat1 = obj1.matrix_world
mat2 = obj2.matrix_world

# Get the geometry in world coordinates
vert1 = [mat1 @ v.co for v in obj1.data.vertices] 
poly1 = [p.vertices for p in obj1.data.polygons]

vert2 = [mat2 @ v.co for v in obj2.data.vertices] 
poly2 = [p.vertices for p in obj2.data.polygons]

# Create the BVH trees
bvh1 = BVHTree.FromPolygons( vert1, poly1 )
bvh2 = BVHTree.FromPolygons( vert2, poly2 )

# Test if overlap
if bvh1.overlap( bvh2 ):
    print( "Overlap" )
else:
    print( "No overlap" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `# Get the objects` part of that script with the script below.

```
# Get the objects
ob1 = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
ob2 = bpy.data.objects["Suzanne"]

# Get the evaluated objects
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
obj1 = ob1.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
obj2 = ob2.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
```

See [types.Depsgraph](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.90/bpy.types.Depsgraph.html?highlight=graph)

Comment: It's working! Thank you