# How to prevent my operators changes to a scene from being saved to file

Tags: python, scripting

My export operator modifies part of the scene before exporting, e. g. apply modifiers, fill holes in meshes. I have to be very careful to only save the scene *before* exporting. I'd like to prevent myself from accidencally saving the scene after the export.

Is there a way to undo everything the operator did?

Or another way, e. g. rename the scene? Mark it as un-saveable?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender  _ie_ make changes to an "export proxy" mesh, in which case there are no saved changes.

Comment: @batFINGER Not sure how that helps. I need to make other changes by calling operators, which can't operate on the proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up duplicating the meshes with `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()`. Requires the mesh to be selected and visible, for some reason, so I unhide it with `o.hide_set(False)`.

I didn't delete the duplicates for testing, which resulted in an infinite loop when iterating over `for o in context.scene.objects`. So I collected all meshes first in a list, then iterated over that list.