# Get Point Coordinates generated with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: python, scripting, coordinates, geometry-nodes, point-clouds

Say you generate some random points using Geometry Nodes, **how can you get all those point coordinates using the python api?**

The only hint I have is that the point coords are located under Point Cloud in the Spreadsheet Editor.

Basically, I want to use those coordinates for scripting other stuff I can't do with Geometry Nodes yet.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a workaround and I hope there is (or will eventually be) an easier way to access point cloud data in the API.

[image]

In your GN tree add an *Instance on Points* node, plug in a *Mesh Line* or a *Points* node set to a *Count* of 1 to get a single vertex at $(0, 0, 0)$.

[image]

In  theory we should be able to access the vertices' geometry but for now the geometry is not "real". We need to realize the instances with a *Realize Instances* node.

[image]

Then, we need to access the evaluated mesh, after the GN modifier has been evaluated. For that we can use the [context dependency graph](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender).

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
obj = bpy.context.active_object.evaluated_get(depsgraph)

coords = np.zeros(len(obj.data.vertices) * 3, dtype=float)
obj.data.vertices.foreach_get("co", coords)

print(coords)  # This is a flattened array

coords = coords.reshape(len(obj.data.vertices), 3)

print(coords)  # This is a 3D array
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: i love workaround if they work!! Great job!

Comment: Yeah, hopefully they simplify this so vertex instancing isn't needed, but for now it works so thank you!

Comment: There is a "points to vertices" node, I don't know if there was back in 2021.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I don't think it did ! Have you tried if it works without the realize instances trick ?

Comment: @Gorgious I did: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/289622/60486