# How to get point cloud produced by GN modifier by python?

Tags: point-clouds

[image]

I create a empty mesh and create many points in PointCloud and want to write a addon to export them, how to get them by python? i find the point cloud type doc, but don't get the api to get them:
PointCloud(ID)
base classes — bpy_struct, ID
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointCloud.html

Comment: I don't think there is yet a way in an official release to get the point cloud data from an object since it's not possible to create a native point cloud object. I suspect your base object is either a Curve or a Mesh object, so `obj.data` will point to a curve or mesh data (splines or polygons/vertices). You can try this method which is a bit hacky to transform the Points to vertices which can be parsed easily (although it may take a while if you have millions of points) see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227129/get-point-coordinates-generated-with-geometry-nodes

Comment: of course happy to be proven wrong :)