# How to export the point cloud coordinates created by the geometry node "distribution points on faces "?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, export, coordinates, point-clouds

[image]

Tried everything I could but cannot find a solution to export it in python code!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227129/get-point-coordinates-generated-with-geometry-nodes A very good solution for the time being!!!