How can I Export Cloud Point Positions to a Spreadsheet from Mesh Volume
I have been trying to obtain the cloud points data. I convert the mesh into a volume and distribute the cloud points within the volume. Here is what I am doing:

I am wondering if there is a way to export the positions shown in the spreadsheet on the left. Currently, I have only found ways to extract the nodes of the mesh.

See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227129/get-point-coordinates-generated-with-geometry-nodes Not sure if the answer has changed.
