# How to convert from SVG to meshes with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert an SVG file to a mesh and then extrude it, using Python, with the later goal of converting SVG paths directly (i.e.: without going through a file)

I get as far as converting the closed path to a curve like this - but fail when trying to create an object (last line):

```
import bmesh

bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(filepath='test.svg')
print('path is ', bpy.data.objects['path38'].type)
path = bpy.data.objects['path38']

dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
path = path.evaluated_get(dg)

mesh = path.to_mesh()
print(mesh);

# this fails:
o = bpy.data.objects.new("myMesh_object", mesh)
```

which fails with message:

```
RuntimeError: Error: Can not create object in main database with an evaluated data data-block
```

So, what's the right way to go from SVG to path to mesh to extruded object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make a copy.**

Can't use the evaluated mesh, can use the copy

[How do I get a mesh data-block with modifiers and shape keys applied in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146573/15543)

Example using bezier circle add,

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add()
path = context.object
print('path is ', path.type)


dg = context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
path = path.evaluated_get(dg)

mesh = path.to_mesh()
print(mesh);

# this fails:
o = bpy.data.objects.new("myMesh_object", mesh.copy())
context.scene.collection.objects.link(o)
```

Comment: It works, thanks - but is it unpolite to ask why this is necessary?

Comment: elaborated in linked answer.

Comment: I read that through before asking - I understand that being evaluated makes things "dirty" and that making a copy somehow "cleans" them, whereas just making them into a mesh doesn't.. But I still don't grasp the underlying logic/reason why. Maybe it's me - I'll try harder. Thanks for all the answers though, this one al all the others I've relied on

Comment: More ephemeral than dirty. An object or  mesh data block 's data is saved in the blend.  Their evaluations are not. Copy creates a new data block.

Comment: If so, please consider to vote up the answer(s) as well @simone See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers