# Why are bones separated from the body during the animation in Edit mode?

Tags: animation, edit-mode

[image]I was doing some animations in Blender 2.93, but in "Edit mode", the bone and the meshed body are separated from each other during animation, just as the pic shows.
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: The _Edit Mode_ is not for animating or posing but as the name suggests for editing the mesh. This means the underlying base mesh, not any deformed mesh created by modifiers, armatures etc.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. So this is normal in edit mode? Doesn't mean the model was destroyed?

Comment: It's not destroyed, just all movements, deformations etc. created by modifiers are deactivated to edit the mesh in its original basic form. The same applies for example if you simply have a cube and add a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier, in _Object Mode_ it gets rounded or spherical, but when you switch to _Edit Mode_ it is shown as cube. That's the default way how Blender works. However, as the answer below shows, there are buttons that let you edit the model with the modifier's modifications visible.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot, Gordon. You solve my confusion. I use the edit mode to get the coordinates of certain vert, this seems hard to do in other modes. And another question occurs, the coordinates of vert seems not to change during the animation, this is strange, what might be the reason for this?

Comment: I have no idea, I never need coordinates of vertices for anything. I can only imagine that the coordinates refer to the local position in the original mesh relative to the object's origin point - i.e. where they are in the object, not in the world and without getting modified by any modifier. For example, the standard cube has 8 vertices with X/Y/Z location either 1 or -1. If you move the cube somewhere else or put a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier on it, the vertices still stay at 1/-1 in _Edit Mode_ no matter where they visually are in _Object Mode_.

Comment: well, coordinates are used in some other programs for further development as Blender is also a good simulator. As for the coordinates in Blender, moving the object in Edit mode, yes its local coordinates will not change, while its global coordinates will change.

Comment: I know that they don't change, I wasn't asking for that. I've only made the assumption that the reason for this is because the _Edit Mode_ doesn't take the modifications into account. How could it? The default cube with a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier at Level 2 for example only has 8 vertices, but with subdivision 98 vertices - only they are all "virtual", not editable. Anyway, that's Blender, not some other program.

Comment: I know what you mean. Edit mode is not designed for getting details of the object but for editing on object, so in this perspective, I shouldn't ask more in it. But also in this mode, more details are presented than other modes because we need to edit so we must know more about the object.  As for my question, I think in Blender, we can get every detail about a object in the scene, no matter how it is enveloped. What I am confused is that I can not find a way to achieve this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the armature modifier enable theese 2 little buttons:

[image]

Comment: what can I say? Little buttons help a lot. This is exactly what I am seeking. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi, josh, I have another question. I chose a vert for example 5254, its coordinates didn't change during the animation. What might be the reason for this?