# How do I removed the stored vertices data in Blender 2.79?

Tags: python, vertices, blend-files, linked-data, data-blocks

Thank you very much for your time, any help would be appreciated.

I have been using the code below to shrinkwrap an Icosphere onto my 3D models, then find the vertices coordinates of the Icosphere and export them into an excel file.

```
    import bpy
    
    thelist = open('The List.txt', 'r')
    name = thelist.readline()
    
    path = r"filepath"+name+".obj"
    FILEPATH = str.join("", path.splitlines())
    
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=FILEPATH)
    
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            obj.name = "Specimen"
    
    bpy.data.objects["Specimen"].select = True
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["Specimen"]
    bpy.context.active_object.scale = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
    bpy.context.active_object.scale = (5, 5, 5)
    
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SHRINKWRAP')
    bpy.data.objects["Icosphere"].modifiers["Shrinkwrap"].target = bpy.data.objects["Specimen"]
    
    with open("Landmarks.csv", "a") as file:
        file.write(name)
        vs = bpy.data.meshes["Icosphere"].vertices
        for v in vs:
            file.write("%.2f, %.2f, %.2f," % (v.co[:]))

for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.type == 'MESH':
        o.select = True
bpy.ops.object.delete()

name = thelist.readline()

path = r"filepath"+name+".obj"
FILEPATH = str.join("", path.splitlines())

bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=FILEPATH)

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        obj.name = "Specimen"

bpy.data.objects["Specimen"].select = True
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["Specimen"]
bpy.context.active_object.scale = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
bpy.context.active_object.scale = (5, 5, 5)

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SHRINKWRAP')
bpy.data.objects["Icosphere"].modifiers["Shrinkwrap"].target = bpy.data.objects["Specimen"]

with open("Landmarks.csv", "a") as file:
    file.write(name)
    vs = bpy.data.meshes["Icosphere"].vertices
    for v in vs:
        file.write("%.2f, %.2f, %.2f," % (v.co[:]))
```

I want to make this process automatic and go through all of my models without having to constantly click around. However, when I duplicated the code, I get a different model in blender but the same coordinates in my excel file from the first Icosphere. I already know that creating a new file clears out this memory, but it means that the programme can't be fully automatic. So how do I clear out those stored vertices without having to create a new file and stop the automatic process?

EDIT: added the duplicated code, as suggested in the comments. Once this issue has been sorted I will be turning the programme into a loop, however, going through the list.

Comment: Issue looks like naming convention. There can only ever by one object named "Specimen" and one named "IcoSphere" in a blend file. Others will be "Specimen.001", ... etc. _eg_  `print(context.object.name)`  after running  the add ico operator .  Similarly with its mesh.   Recommend reference them, eg after ico op `ico = context.object` and use `ico` as object ref and `ico.data` rather than `bpy.data.meshes["IcoSphere"]` from then on.

Comment: Hi @batFINGER, thank you so much for the quick comment! I think I understand what you mean about the naming convention being the issue, but I'm not sure I quite understand the recommendation, could that be explained again, please?

Comment: The issue would be in what you replaced or did not replace when you copy/pasted the code. Could you add your 2nd version in your question ? The answer will definitely be there

Comment: @gorgious Updated the code to what I was using when I duplicated the code. This is what gave me 2 different models but the same vertices landmarks added to the excel file.

Answer (score 1):

**Can't be certain of name.**

Further to my comment,

> Issue looks like naming convention. There can only ever by one object
> named "Specimen" and one named "IcoSphere" in a blend file. Others
> will be "Specimen.001", ... etc. eg `print(context.object.name)` after
> running the add ico operator . Similarly with its mesh. Recommend
> reference them, eg after ico op `ico = context.object` and use `ico` as
> object ref and `ico.data` rather than `bpy.data.meshes["IcoSphere"]` from
> then on.

For example, a test in the console.

Add an icosphere

```
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Icosphere']

>>> C.object.data
bpy.data.meshes['Icosphere']
```

Remove it

```
>>> bpy.ops.object.delete()
Info: Deleted 1 object(s)
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.object is None
True
```

But wait!!! there's still a mesh named "Icosphere"

```
>>> D.meshes['
              Cube']
              Icosphere']
>>> D.meshes['Icosphere']
bpy.data.meshes['Icosphere']
```

Let's add another Icosphere object

```
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Icosphere']
```

And here's the issue, the object is removed, the mesh not, the new ones mesh is not named "Icosphere"

```
>>> C.object.data
bpy.data.meshes['Icosphere.001']
```

There are a number of ways to fix, including removing both the object and the mesh, but as a general rule would, reference it after adding by by operator

```
>>> bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add()
{'FINISHED'}

>>> ico = C.object 
>>> ico_mesh = ico.data
>>> ico_mesh
bpy.data.meshes['Icosphere.002']
```

and use

```
vs = ico_mesh.vertices
```

to always use the mesh of the newly added icosphere.

As a rule of thumb, rarely or never use

```
bpy.data.whatevers[name]
```

as there is a chance it will not be *"Who you think it is"*

Similarly, for the modifier

```
>>> sw = ico.modifiers.new("Foo", 'SHRINKWRAP')
>>> sw
bpy.data.objects['Icosphere.001'].modifiers["Foo"]
    
>>> sw.object = target
```

Where target is an object assigned earlier from imported.

```
>>> target
bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

And finally, if the desired result is the locations of the modified verticies, either apply the modifier,

```
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=sw.name)
```

or, IMO preferably use one of [How do I get a mesh data-block with modifiers and shape keys applied in Blender 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender)