# Low level alternative for bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, bezier-curves

Since Blender 2.93 hair system not support curves anymore,
I have to convert them to meshes.

Trying to replace bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

with obj.to_mesh() function.
but,
It is not able to keep attributes like the ops option can.

any ideas?
thanks

```
import bpy

try :
    hair_colection = bpy.data.collections['Hairs']
    hairs_objects = hair_colection.all_objects


    for hair in hairs_objects:
        if hair.type == 'CURVE':
            hair.select_set(True)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = hair
            bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
            print (hair,hair.type)
except:
    print( "no hairs collection")
```

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate on which attributes are lost in the process ?

Comment: And why do you not want to use the operator ? Have you seen this q&a ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146911/86891

Comment: Might also be that the context is not initialized yet. Use a timer to wait for a little bit before executing the logic eg https://blenderartists.org/t/run-text-data-block-from-command-line-post-context/1356926