# How can I convert a CURVE to a MESH object

Tags: python, bmesh

I am trying to convert all the curves in a blendfile to meshes - like this, as explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39881/is-there-a-low-level-alternative-for-bpy-ops-object-convert):

```
import bpy

for obj in [ obj for obj in bpy.data.objects  ]:
    if obj.type == "CURVE":
        print(obj, obj.type, obj.parent.type)
        print([ o.type for o in getChildren(obj.parent) ])

        dg  = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
        obj = dg.objects.get(obj.name)
        
        me = obj.to_mesh()
        print(len(me.vertices))
        try:
            o = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name + "Mesh", me)
        except Exception as e:     
            print(e)
```

However it throws an error:

```
 Error: Can not create object in main database with an evaluated data data-block
```

I've also tried using:

```
 obj = obj.evaluated_get(dg)
```

like explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146559/how-do-i-get-a-mesh-data-block-with-modifiers-and-shape-keys-applied-in-blender) but this fails too.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to use the depsgraph, but you have a Python issue:  You are using `obj` both as the loop variable _and_ as a variable within the loop.  Try changing the internal name to something else.

Answer (score 4):

The docs of [bpy.types.Object.to_mesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) state :

> The result is temporary and can not be used by objects from the main database

Which means you can't use this evaluated mesh as data for an actual object in the scene. It will be thrown to the garbage collector once the scope it was created in completes.

As the other answer suggest, you may want to use the [bpy.ops.object.convert](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html) operator to do it. I would add the optional `keep_original` argument since your code seems to hint that you want to keep the original curves.

As I discovered in [my endeavour to document all operator overrides](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248275/86891), this operator [can't be overriden](https://developer.blender.org/T93188). So you'll have to select objects by code.

```
import bpy


bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')


for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == 'CURVE':
        obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH', keep_original=True)
```

You can also use lower-level functions :

```
import bpy


for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.type == "CURVE":
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new_from_object(obj)
        new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name, mesh)
        new_obj.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(new_obj)
```

Credit https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277424/86891 and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataMeshes.html#bpy.types.BlendDataMeshes.new_from_object

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there is an even simpler solution, if you `copy` the evaluated mesh, it will create a mesh datablock you can use for real.

```py
import bpy

for obj in bpy.data.objects[:]:
    if obj.type == "CURVE":
        me = obj.to_mesh()
        o = bpy.data.objects.new(obj.name + "Mesh", me.copy())
        o.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(o)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK to convert a curve to an object you have to select it. So I guess you can do something like this:

```py
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
```